# Show X if Time between A and B when F7 and I7 given the time

Tags: google-sheets

I have the times in the columns U V W X which are: night, tomorrow, noon and evening.

Now sheet should do this so that it compares on the one hand on the date U3 with date E7 / H7 which works.

U7 with formula:

```
=if(and(U$3>=$E7,U$3<=$H7),$D7&"a",if(and(U$3>=$J7,U$3<=$L7),"=",if(and(U$3>=$N7,U$3<=$Q7),$M7&"x","")))
```

But now he should be in me

Show U7 only if the time is between 00:00 and 05:59

Show V7 only if the time is between 06:00 and 11:59

Show W7 only when the time is between 12:00 and 17:59

Can one of you help me?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bpJF6-rLNCHvr1ybSNBbNTMmCSf9nPBK-4p-m9XfEdc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Would you edit your spreadsheet to show a successful outcome. At present in row 7, values are displayed in both cells U7 AND V7; and in row 8 and 9, no cells are displayed at all.

Comment: May I clarify? Please correct me if I am wrong. Sub-Task start times are in cells E7/F7, E8/F8 & E9/F9. The first cell is the date and the second cell is the time. The period beginning Monday covers fours Columns - U, V, W and X. A formula in each column in rows 7, 8 & 9 displays a value in each column. Your goal is to modify the formula so that the value appears only in one of the four columns: U, start time between 00:00 and 06:00 (evening); V, start time between 06:00 and 12:00 (morning);W, start time between 12:00 and 18:00 (afternoon); and X, start time between 18:00 and 00:00 (night).

Comment: @Tedinoz Thats correct you can edit the file thath i shard https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bpJF6-rLNCHvr1ybSNBbNTMmCSf9nPBK-4p-m9XfEdc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you. Would you re-read the first comment, and edit the spreadsheet to show a successful outcome. You can always add a sheet called "Successful Outcome" and edit the relevant cells to show which should be displayed.